# NoSuchElementException in selenium while scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract project information from [text](https://stackoverflow.com)https://reporter.nih.gov/search/yy5Vbj7JUUq4HMrFAEuIJg/projects
Using Selenium enter a link like
[text](https://stackoverflow.com)https://reporter.nih.gov/search/yy5Vbj7JUUq4HMrFAEuIJg/project-details/10617263
I wash and want to find and click the view email button, but it does not find this button and gives an error
this is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver)
for url in project_urls:
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    button = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH , value="//*[@id='details']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/button")
    button.click()
    email = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH , value="//*[@id='details']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/a").text
    print(email)
    driver.close()
```

It gives NoSuchElementException error. I also tested finding with CSS selector and class name and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply Selenium's [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) for the page to load completely before it can locate desired elements.

Refer the code below where I have applied `Explicit Waits`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://reporter.nih.gov/search/yy5Vbj7JUUq4HMrFAEuIJg/project-details/10617263")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='details']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/button")))
button.click()
email = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='details']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/a"))).text
print(email)
driver.close()
```

**Console output:**

```
ma_a@dfci.harvard.edu

Process finished with exit code 0
```